# convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4n^2+5n}{n(n^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I can't find a way to decide whether it convergent or not... tried the root test, but the result is 1(which means nothing)

Comment: Comparison test against $\frac{1}{n^2}$ ?

Comment: tried - couldn't figure out how it helps me - how do i show that $\frac{1}{n^2} $ is greater than the sequence

Comment: Hm, doesn't $0<\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{(4n^2+5n)n^2}{n(n^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=4<\infty$ imply needed convergence? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: observe that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4n^2+5n}{n(n^2+1)^{\frac32}}.n^2=4
$$

Comment: very easy solution. used that idea

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $0\leq \frac{4n^2+5n}{n(n^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\leq \frac{4n^2+5n}{n^4}\leq \frac{9n^2}{n^4}\leq \frac{9}{n^2}$ and by M-test it is convergent

Answer (score 0):

The series is convergent because you can find a constant $K$ large enough such that the terms are less than $\frac{K}{n^2}$ and you then use M-test to conclude.